# LTSpice: represent group delay when x axis changes

Tags: ac, ltspice, delay, bode-plot

I am trying to plot the group delay of the following circuit. Usually it is enough to change the y axis from phase to group delay. However because I changed the x axis to represent a normalized angular frequency, that option does not appear. Is there a way to bypass this?

[image]

Comment: Why did you shrink the picture? For my part, I can't read anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to make out your command cards (e.g., .ac), but it looks like you are using a list of frequencies. As you found out, this technique disables group delay in LTSpice.

Perhaps use the traditional .ac command (e.g., `.ac dec 100 .01 10`) to get your group delay. You can save the results to a text file (right-mouse click on graph -> File -> Export data as text) and plot in a graphing program such as gnuplot or Excel with a conversion of the x-axis to radians. If this is for a report, gnuplot will produce textbook looking graphs if you know how to set up your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually take the derivative of phase with respect to frequency in the waveform viewer. Where phase is

$$ \angle H(\omega) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\Im\{H(\omega)\}}{\Re\{H(\omega)\}} \right)$$

And selecting linear for Magnitude Response.

[image]